# Regex PHP Function

Tags: php, regex, tokenize

Yes, I know that people don't like parsing PHP, use a tokenizer they said, it will be great they said... I want you to know it isn't great, it isn't even fine.

I am working in .NET and using PCRE-NET and want to parse some PHP Functions to see if I can do some PHP tree shaking.

I tried using `CodeParser` which uses `Antlr4` to tokenize, the results I got back were horrible to navigate. Yes it is all there technically, but it is so convoluted that really, Regex is better for what I am looking for.

I have the following regex working:

```
(?<functionScope>\w+)\s*function\s+(?<functionName>\w+)\s*\((?<functionArguments>(?:[^()]+)*)?\s*\)[\s:]*.*(?<functionBody>{(?:[^{}]+|(?-1))*+})
```

Try it out: https://regex101.com/r/yU6K45/1

This will break up a PHP File into the individual scopes, functions, arguments and function body. I am now looking at the `functionBody` and wanting to find all functions used inside that function, which I have here:

```
(?=[^\=\s])((?<functionClass>[$?\w[\w\d]*)?(?<ClassOperator>::|->|\\)?){0,3}?(?<functionName>\w[\w\d]*)\((?<Arguments>.*)?\)
```

See it at: https://regex101.com/r/3JzPR5/1

An issue I am having is with named groups. When there is a lot of namespacing, the named groups don't work out well. I am wondering if you have any ideas how to split up the line:

```
  $uri = ExtraLevel\Psr7\UriResolver::resolve(Psr7\Utils::uriFor($config['base_uri']), $uri);
```

To where I would have something like:

```
Full match               ExtraLevel\Psr7\UriResolver::resolve(Psr7\Utils::uriFor($config['base_uri']), $uri)
Group `functionClass`    ExtraLevel\
Group `functionClass2`   Psr7\
Group `functionClass3`   UriResolver::
Group `functionName`     resolve
Group `Arguments`        Psr7\Utils::uriFor($config['base_uri']), $uri
```

Would love to match in a way that won't break when there aren't 3-4 levels.

Comment: PHP itself has a [builtin tokenizer](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.tokenizer.php). Perhaps you can write a simple PHP script that extracts the info you need into a format that's suitable to be consumed by .NET (JSON or whatever).

Comment: I am questioning this syntax: `[$?\w[\w\d]*` please express your intention.

Comment: It would grab the classname, or whether it was private / public